# My indexOf() is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

The link to my project is here:
http://codepen.io/xruizify/pen/aJKpNJ

```
var reservedTimes = [];

$(function() {                       
   var idx = reservedTimes.indexOf(currentSelection);
   $("td").click(function() { 
      var selectedTime = $(this).parent().prop('className');
      var weekDay = $(this).prop('className').split(" ")[0];
      var currentSelection = weekDay + "and" + selectedTime;
      //var idx = reservedItems.indexOf(currentSelection); It didn't work here
      if ( $(this).is(".reserved") ) {  

      } else if($(this).is(".active")) {
        $(this).removeClass("active"); 
        //var idx = reservedItems.indexOf(currentSelection); I get 'undefined'
        document.getElementById("currentIDX").innerHTML = idx;   
        //The comment below is what I want to do in the future once idx works
        //reservedTimes.splice(idx,1);
        printTimes();      
      } else{
        $(this).addClass("active"); 
        document.getElementById("mainHeader").innerHTML = selectedTime;      
        document.getElementById("currentSelection").innerHTML = currentSelection; 
        document.getElementById("currentIDX").innerHTML = idx;
        document.getElementById("secondHeader").innerHTML = weekDay;
        reservedTimes.push(currentSelection);
        printTimes(); 
   } 
 });
});
function makeReservation() {
  $(".active").addClass("reserved");
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  printTimes();
 }
 function printTimes() {
   document.getElementById("timeTitle").innerHTML = reservedTimes;
 }
```

Basically, you click a cell in the table, it generates a special "code" and adds it to an array. Each cell in the table always makes the same unique code and it does not change. I want to be able to take that, get the indexOf() value of it in the array and remove it once clicking it a second time. No matter where I declared the idx variable, it wouldn't work and I can't figure this one out.

Comment: `reservedItems` or `reservedTimes`? You’re using both, but only `reservedTimes` is defined. You do not get `undefined` where it says `I get 'undefined'`. `indexOf` doesn’t ever return `undefined`. `var idx = reservedTimes.indexOf(currentSelection);` at your second position should work.

Comment: Where you use `document.getElementById("mainHeader").innerHTML = selectedTime;`, why not just do `$("#mainHeader").html(selectedTime);` (since you're utilizing **jQuery**)

Comment: Oops, typo. But changing it to 'reservedTimes' still gives me a -1 @Xufox

Comment: Great suggestion @GROVER.

Comment: @XavierRuiz Changing it to `reservedTimes`? But did you also change the position? I do get `0` or `1` if it’s not the first click.

Comment: @Xufox Thank you, I didn't realize i had it wrong multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're trying to call `indexOf` on `reservedItems` which doesn't exist; I think you mean `reservedTimes` which is your array that you are pushing to and then you can call `splice` on it as you are.

This works as intended in your codepen (fixed http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XMYpxa):

```
var reservedTimes = [];

$(function() {                          
  $("td").click(function() { 
    var selectedTime = $(this).parent().prop('className');
    var weekDay = $(this).prop('className').split(" ")[0];
    var currentSelection = weekDay + "and" + selectedTime;
    var idx = reservedTimes.indexOf(currentSelection); 
    if ( $(this).is(".reserved") ) {  

    } else if($(this).is(".active")) {
      $(this).removeClass("active"); 
      document.getElementById("currentIDX").innerHTML = idx;
      reservedTimes.splice(idx,1);
      printTimes();      
    } else{
      $(this).addClass("active"); 
      document.getElementById("mainHeader").innerHTML = selectedTime;      
      document.getElementById("currentSelection").innerHTML = currentSelection; 
      document.getElementById("currentIDX").innerHTML = idx;
      document.getElementById("secondHeader").innerHTML = weekDay;
      reservedTimes.push(currentSelection);
      printTimes(); 
    } 
  });

});
function makeReservation() {
    $(".active").addClass("reserved");
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    printTimes();
}
function printTimes(){
  document.getElementById("timeTitle").innerHTML = reservedTimes;
}
```